# Taylor expansion of $f(z)=\frac{z+1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ at $z_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$$

I tried to compute $f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ and $\frac{z+1}{z-2}$ separately but it didnt work...Appreciate any help!

Comment: Use the partial fraction version of $f(z)$.  Then you only have to add two geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Noticing that $z + 1 = 3 \, (z-1) - 2 \, (z-2)$ leads to
$$ \frac{z+1}{(z-1)(z-2)} = \frac{3}{z-2} - \frac{2}{z-1} = \frac{2}{1-z} - \frac{3}{2} \, \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z}{2}}.$$
From this point it is fairly easy to obtained the desired coefficients of the expansion.